# Oracle SQL create a virtual column, do a max and then count and displaying records

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if the title is a bit misleading but I don't know how else to put it. Anyways back to problem at hand. I have 2 tables WSM(contains warehouse id, name and risk associated with it) and SUTSM_REP(store and warehouse relation). Below are values what they hold:
[WSM table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJL0y.png)

[SUTSM_REP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGW7M.png)

Every warehouse has a risk associated with it(4 risks categories - Low, Medium, High & Critical) and a store gets stuff from multiple warehouses. If a store gets stuff from 3 warehouses(say for eg w1(medium risk), w2(high), w3(low)) then the risk associated with the store is 'High'. Similarly if a store gets stuff from 2 warehouses - 1 with medium and another with low risk then the store gets 'Medium' risk. I hope I am clear with this point. I was asked to bring up the count of Stores with each risk. So what I did was I created another table with risk and risk id. I assigned 1 to Low, 2 to medium, 3 to high and 4 to critical. Then I joined the 3 tables along with max of risk id and then did a count of that. Below is my query :

```
select RID, count(sp_id)
from
  (select a.sp_id, max(c.r_id) AS RID
   from SUTSM_REP a,
        WSM b,
        wsm_rid c
   where a.sm_id = b.sm_id and b.smr = c.smr
   group by a.sp_id) t
group by RID;
```

And the result is :[my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kBoP.png)

But boss doesn't want a 3rd table to be created and he wants Risk names (Low, Medium, High, Critical) instead of Risk IDs. So I modified the query to :

```
with t as (
  select sm_id, sm_name, smr, DECODE(smr, 'Low', 1,
                                    'Medium', 2,
                                    'High', 3,
                                    'Critical', 4,
                                    0) RISK_ID 
   from wsm )
select rid, count(sp_id) from 
    ( select sp_id, max(risk_id) rid 
      from (select a.sp_id, b.sm_id, b.risk_id 
            from SUTSM_REP a, t b 
            where a.sm_id=b.sm_id) 
       group by sp_id ) 
group by rid;
```

I created a temp table using the wsm and added the risk id to the risk category/level. And then used the same logic as earlier. [Output of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLK9G.png) is :

We use Oracle SQL. Can anyone please help me or point me in the direction of how to get the names of Risk Categories/Levels? I am at my wits end here. Thanks in advance to any posters for their help.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.   I find the rest of the question equally hard to follow.

Comment: But we have been using JOIN in Oracle the way above since the last 4 years. I know we dont use "INNER JOIN" key word but select a.*, b.* from tab1 a, tab2 b where a.col1=b.col1 is a valid syntax. Correct me if I am wrong. Also I am sorry about the formatting. I see I messed it up. I am trying to edit the post now.

Comment: The unreadable join syntax blends well with your inscrutable table and columns names and the non-mnemonic alias names, by the way. ; -) Are you trying to make your programming life as hard as possible? Whats wrong with calling a warehouse table `warehouse` or `warehouses`, a store ID `store_id` or with abbreviating a `warehouse` table `wh` instead of `a`, `b`, or `c`?

Comment: @Throsten - I'm sorry for the table and column names. I didn't do that on the actual Production environment. In order to keep it short I had to make those temp tables in the local SQL Developer on my laptop. Thats what all the screenshots You see. Next time I'll keep that in mind. Thanks. But "unreadable JOIN syntax". I take it You prefer the syntax table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column, am I right? But the way I typed is also correct, isnt it?

Comment: Yes that old syntax is still allowed, but looked at with disdain. The old syntax is more prone to errors. E.g. is a mere `from a, b` an indended `from a cross join b` or has the join criteria mistakenly been forgotton or deleted (`from a inner join b on ____`)? With `from a inner join b` you are forced to place a join criteria, otherwise you'll get a syntax error. Outer joins are very hard to read with the old syntax and full outer joins are even impossible (but could be emulated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to have a risk table holding the risk names and their relevance. If you are not allowed to create such table, create them as an ad-hoc view with `WITH` on-the-fly.

The next step is getting the highest risk per store, which can be got with a join to above risk table and `KEEP LAST`.

The last step is counting stores per risk.

```
with risks as
(
  select 'Low' as smr, 1 as relevance from dual
  union all
  select 'Medium' as smr, 2 as relevance from dual
  union all
  select 'High' as smr, 3 as relevance from dual
  union all
  select 'Critical' as smr, 4 as relevance from dual
)
, store_risks as
(
  select
    sw.sp_id,
    max(w.smr) keep (dense_rank last order by r.relevance) as risk,
    max(r.relevance) as risk_sortkey
  from sutsm_rep sw -- the store/warehouse bridge
  join wsm w on w.sm_id = sw.sm_id -- the warehouses
  join risks r on r.smr = w.smr -- the risks
  group by sw.sp_id
)
select risk, count(*)
from store_risks
group by risk
order by max(risk_sortkey);
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten!! It worked and I learnt something new (the part after with risks as..). I had no idea a full table could be created that way. I knew about with clause and have used it in past but this just opens up a whole new world for me. Thanks again :). How do I upvote Your answer? Sorry I am new to posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to *upvote* yet. New users have very limited rights. Once you have the right, there will be an upvote triange next to the answer you can click (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments). You should  be able to *accept* one answer, though, which you should do, when your request is properly answered and solved (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to `decode` the RISK_ID back into the respective categories? Sample below ..

```
with t as (
  select sm_id, sm_name, smr, DECODE(smr, 'Low', 1,
                                    'Medium', 2,
                                    'High', 3,
                                    'Critical', 4,
                                    0) RISK_ID 
   from wsm )
select rid, 
DECODE(rid, 1, 'Low',
            2, 'Medium',
            3, 'High',
            4, 'Critical') smr,
count(sp_id) from 
    ( select sp_id, max(risk_id) rid 
      from (select a.sp_id, b.sm_id, b.risk_id 
            from SUTSM_REP a, t b 
            where a.sm_id=b.sm_id) 
       group by sp_id ) 
group by rid;
```

Alternatively, you may use the `rank` function

```
select smr, count(distinct sp_id) from (
select s.sp_id, w.smr,
rank () over (partition by s.sp_id order by 
DECODE(smr, 'Low', 1,
            'Medium', 2,
            'High', 3,
            'Critical', 4,
             0) desc
) rnk
from wsm w
join sutsm_rep s on w.sm_id = s.sm_id
) where rnk = 1
group by smr
;
```

If this doesn't work, please share your expected output. Also, please consider using db fiddle. I've added a sample [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e541f09e866359997b3a581f0d55fbd3).